# Javascript keeps duplicated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i want to make a simple note system. Each time you press the add button a new note pops up, however it keeps copying the content. meaning i start off with 1 note, add 1, click again, and then have 4, click again, now 8.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(".notes").after('<div class="notes"><div class=container><div class="card"><div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light"><img class="activator" src="images/keyboard.jpg"></div><div class="card-content"><span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span></div><div class="card-reveal"><span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span><p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p></div></div></div></div>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<div class="notes">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                <img class="activator" src="images/keyboard.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try $(".notes").append(your content here)

Comment: $(".notes:last").after('<div class="notes">....');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're appending after every element with a class `notes` the new content, which has a new div with class `notes`. Remove it or change name to one of the two classes (or use `last()` as suggested in other answer).

So at the beginning you have this:

```
<div class="notes">...</div>
```

After you click the button once, you have something like that:

```
<div class="notes">...</div>
<div class="notes">...</div>
```

Now, if you click the button again, jQuery will append the new note after every note class:

```
<div class="notes">...</div>
<div class="notes">...</div>  <-- New note
<div class="notes">...</div>
<div class="notes">...</div>  <-- New note
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting on the class `notes`, and then adding a new element with that same class. So the next time you click the button, it matches both the original, and the new item. Third time you press it it matches both, and adds 2 duplcaites (one after each).

Use a different class for the added content, or specify a particular one in the selector using something like `:first` or `:last`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(".notes:last").after('<div class="notes"><div class=container><div class="card"><div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light"><img class="activator" src="images/keyboard.jpg"></div><div class="card-content"><span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span></div><div class="card-reveal"><span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span><p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p></div></div></div></div>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<div class="notes">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                <img class="activator" src="images/keyboard.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```